# Spring security login does not work after a while

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security, jpa-2.0

I'm using spring security and spring mvc 3.0.5 and mysql (hibernate+jpa). The spring security works very well, but after a while it stops working and a valid login attempt results in an login error, after trying the same credentials 3 to 4 times the login start to work. Is this i known issue or does someone can give me some pointer where to look? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the debug, Luke... (Add `log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG` to `/main/resources/log4j.properties`.)

Comment: Turned on the debugger like advised (thank you for the tip Master Yoda).

The log says : 

`org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory - SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]`

There is no exception. After a failed login attempt the second/third try works.

Comment: There must be something else in log - edit your question and add complete log output because so far it's impossible to say anything about the problem. It should be something like `11:18:39.123 FilterChainProxy - /user/login at position 1 of 16 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'`

Comment: After analyzing the logs i found the cause of the problem. The database connection was timing out after a while. My connection pool implementation was not working correctly. Now i use C3P0 for pooling my connections and the login works like a charm. Thank you for your input.